# Viewport for phones only

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries

I am trying to make a responsive layout that has a phone view and a normal view only (ie. Tablets should load the page normally).

Everything is working correctly as far as the CSS goes however the viewport is screwing up the zoom on tablets when they're in portrait mode. (They're zoomed in to their pixel width)

Is there a way to get tablets to zoom out to the full page while still having the phones load scaled to their size?

Here's what I have... Changing the initial scale to .75 almost works but then the iPhone loads the normal site when in landscape, which I don't want.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width: 568px)" href="css/mobile-styles.css" />
```

Comment: Max scale is awful for usability. Don't do it. Let users zoom if th want.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mess with the viewport, it'll only cause headaches and accessibility issues. Instead, create the CSS you want for phones(small screens) and then include the styles for the "full" site (large screens) in a `min-width:500px`(or some other breakpoint) media query.

Example CSS:

```
/*this will fire for any size screen*/
nav{
  width:100%;
}

/*this changes the above styles for any screen over 500px*/
@media (min-width:500px){
  nav{
    width:50%;
    float:left;
  }
}
```